# Template does not always see its variables

Tags: symfony, twig

I will first present to you the incriminated templates.

To begin with, I have my layout template with the JQuery. To avoid multiple "$(document).ready()" I placed a block after the general JavaScript.

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Some JS

        {% block jquery %}
        {% endblock %}
    });
</script>

{# Some HTML & JS #}

<body>
    <!-- Some HTML -->
    <div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- Some more HTML -->
</body>
```

It is extended by the template layout_cart.html.twig.

```
{# layout_cart.html.twig #}
{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% block titre %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    <div id="content-container">
        {% block subcontent %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Which is extended itself by panier.html.twig

```
{# panier.html.twig #}
{% extends AppBundle:layout_cart.html.twig #}

{# Some code #}

{% block jquery %}
    // Some JavaScript
    {% for produit in produits %}
        // Generating some JavaScript
    {% endfor %}
    {{ dump(produits) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block subcontent %}
    {% if produits is defined and produits|length > 0 %}
        {{ dump(produits) }}
        {# Interacting with the variables #}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The dump in the jquery renders this :

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
<i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>
```

While in the subcontent it renders my objects collection.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I doubt the variable produits is first time empty and second time not. {{ dump(produits) }} produces HTML code, so if you use this in jquery block, then HTML code inside of Javascript block probably produces javascript syntax error and this dump is not "visible" on web page. Is that why you think it is "empty" ?

Comment: What Miro said: simples way to debug is to see the page source before it gets rendered (aka. right click "See page source").

Comment: I edited my question as I placed the dump to check my assumption and therefore had the proof that it was empty.

Comment: In template panier.html.twig switch position of blocks jquery and subcontent, still the same behavior on output ?

Comment: Well, it actually fixed the problem. Thank you.